# How to use completion handler of PushKit for reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID

Tags: ios, callkit, pushkit

I am using CallKit for my application.

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type withCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(void))completion
{
    NSDictionary *payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"aps"];           

    [self reportIncomingCallFrom:callerName withUUID:self.uuidCallkit completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

    }];
    if (completion) {
        completion();
    }
}
```

My question is: should I write if completion then call completion, or directly call `completion();`? So which one is correct?

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type withCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(void))completion
{
    NSDictionary *payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"aps"];           

    [self reportIncomingCallFrom:callerName withUUID:self.uuidCallkit completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

    }];

    completion();
}
```

this is the method of report incoming call.

```
- (void)reportIncomingCallFrom:(NSString *) from withUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid completion:(nullable void (^)(NSError *_Nullable error))completion
{
    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:from];
    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];

    callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle;
    callUpdate.supportsDTMF = YES;
    callUpdate.supportsHolding = NO;
    callUpdate.supportsGrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.hasVideo = NO;

    NSLog(@"income uuid here for income call %@",uuid);

    [self.callKitProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID: uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Incoming call successfully reported.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to report incoming call successfully: %@.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        completion(error);
    }];
}
```

Sometimes I don't receive the push in background.

I would like to know if my methods above are correct.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to know which between the first and the second snippet of code is correct? Try to edit the question to better explain the problem.

Comment: Hi Marco, Yes, The question is,   if (completion) {
            completion();
    } or only call     completion();. I believe it should call only completion handler but in some example they check it complete then call completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, calling `completion()` directly or checking whether it's not `nil` before, it's equivalent because `completion` has been declared to be `nonnull`.

So, you can just call `completion()` directly and if you have an issue, it's not because of that.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't matter if you check for `completion()` since it's `nonnull` - I see another issue with the code which could lead to VOIP push not being delivered.

You are supposed to call `completion()` from inside of the CallKit provider completion block. That notifies the system that you finished VOIP push processing and made a call to CallKit.

However, you call it asynchronously with notifying CallKit, so the chances are that a race condition could happen there as you have multiple `NSLog()` calls inside. If you call push processing completion block before notifying CallKit about an incoming call - starting from iOS 13 the system most probably would kill your application.

The correct method would be as follows:

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry  didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type withCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(void))completion
{

    NSDictionary *payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"aps"];           

    [self reportIncomingCallFrom:callerName withUUID:self.uuidCallkit completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        
        completion();

    }];

}
```

I'd also move the calls to `NSLog()` after calling the completion block.